# Calculating cost in dollars for smart contract deployment

Tags: solidity, ropsten

I am calculating amount of dollars needed to deploy one of my smart contract.
Gas used for the transaction is `1922666`. My calculation is as below. Is it correct ? I feel this is huge amount in dollars.

Ethers per gas - 0.0000001

Total ethers needed for my transaction is - 1922666 * .0000001 = 0.1922666

When I was doing the calculation 1 ether was 648 dollars so

.192666 ether = 124.5887568 dollars.

Is this correct ? 124 dollars is to high cost right for just deploying one smart contract. Am I doing anything wrong ?

When I checked the same in [gas station](https://ethgasstation.info/index.php) I get only around 1 dollar. Please check the attached screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have tx hash, check it here - https://ropsten.etherscan.io
2. there is price 0.9 Gwei on the screenshot. 0.9 Gwei == 0.0000000009 Eth (https://etherconverter.online). So, 1922666 gas * 0.0000000009 Eth * $751 = $1.2995299494.

**PS:** In case you need more info related to gas, have a look at this article - https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/gas/what-is-gas-ethereum.html

Comment: Ohk. Can we specify cost of 1 gas while calling transaction ?

Comment: Sure, you want to set gasPrice for that value. You have pointed it with **Ethers per gas - 0.0000001** in your post. gasPrice is set by default, but you can adjust it.